# How can I increase the row width in zurb Foundation?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am learning Zurb foundation, and my question is that how can I increase the default width of the row in the framework.

Like a 960 grid system has 960 px. How can I increase the wish of row to maybe 1200px, so should I add a custom stylesheet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to use `!important`. Just place your new CSS—say `app.css`—below the `foundation.css` and use the following:

```
.row {
    max-width: .px;
}
```

You can also use another class and add this property so that it won’t conflict with the default row.

Comment: This works, but in my case it also restricted the max width of a full width row, so if you have full width rows in your layout you might want to reset .row.full-width to 100%

Answer (score 5):

Better way is to go to the **_settings.scss** file of foundation in your project, check online if you don't have _settings.css file or if you don't know its location please. just open and find this

```
$row-width: rem-calc(980); //change up to what you want
```

and this upper value will generate row-width like below value i.e 61.25rem.

```
/* line 228, ../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss */
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 61.25rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

but now if you change that row-width from 980 to something like 1280, like below example

```
$row-width: rem-calc(1280);
```

then you can see below that my css is generated automatically with the new max-width

```
/* line 228, ../../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss */
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

be careful with that settings because you can change the look and layout of whole website drastically.

Answer (score 4):

Override the max-width property of your .row class, and set it to the width you want.

```
.row {
    max-width: ...px !important;
}
```

If you'r using SASS, search for **grid variables** in the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html), where you'll find info on how to override row width, gutter width and more.

```
$row-width: em-calc(1000);
```

Comment: Better never use `!important` and learn about CSS specificity. Smashing mag has a brilliant article about it http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: True, you can always override it by including the .row{} after the Foundation css styles - and thus omitting the !important. Or just use SASS. :) PS. even ZURB uses alot of !important; in their framework - so it can be useful in certain cases.

Answer (score -1):

Foundation 6 introduces the class `.expanded` to make the width fluid: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#fluid-row

It still results in problems with the padding though, no idea how to fix this.